# Default Fallback Intent responses + webhook fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm looking to add some logging of utterances that hit the default fallback intent.  I imagine that's a pretty common desire, so maybe I'm missing some out of the box functionality that would be the real answer.. if so, please let me know!

That said, I'm trying to make use of the default text Responses section of the dialogflow UI, and additionally use a webhook to log the utterance.

I haven't tried this combination before, and I'm not sure how you are intended to do it.  The user gets one of the text responses, and my webhook is called, but it seems that the webhook is expected to return a response as well.  I can't simply log the utterance and be done.

Additionally i can't add suggestion pills, b/c a simple response is also required to be paired with that, even though the user already got a simple response from the default text responses.

Is it a valid use case to have your text response come from the intent responses section in the dialogflow UI, and still use a webhook to do "other" stuff?  If so what is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way, don't return a JSON response and Dialogflow will use what you have sent in the response. This is not unusual, although most people tend to switch to doing responses through webhooks.

Comment: Google support actually got back to me and said "this is not the intended usage"

That said I'm not really confident in that response.  If that is the case, then both the UI is very poorly designed, and the dialogflow application code is not working correctly.